# Basic Google Guice injection. Playframework 2.1

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, playframework-2.1

I'm very new to Google Guice and I'm having troubles to get UserService instanced.
In my Playframework application, I have a service called UserService which looks like this:

```
public class UserService { // Note it doesn't implement an interface
    private UserDao userDao;
    private Email email;

    @Inject
    public UserService(UserDao userDao, Email email) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
        this.email = email;
    }

    ...
}
```

I have this controller:

```
public class UserController extends Controller {
    @Inject
    private UserService userService;

    ...
}
```

I have this `configure()` definition for my UserModule:

```
protected void configure() {
    bind(UserDao.class).to(UserDaoJpa.class);
    bind(Email.class).to(EmailHtml.class);
    bind(UserController.class);
}
```

I get the injector on Playframework Global object which looks similar to the example provided by Guillaume Bort about getting a controller instance, which in this case fits perfectly for getting the injector (the method getControllerInstance is a new feature in Play 2.1, but this is not relevant here). See [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/documentation/manual/javaGuide/main/inject/JavaInjection.md) if interested:

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {
    private static final Injector injector = createInjector();

    @Override
    public <A> A getControllerInstance(Class<A> controllerClass) throws Exception {
        return injector.getInstance(controllerClass);
    }

    private static Injector createInjector() {
        return Guice.createInjector(new UsuarioModule());
    }
}
```

At this point, everything works perfectly, the service is correctly instantiated with its parameters resolved. The controller gets the object graph as expected.
But, when I try to do `@Inject UserService userService` somewhere else in the application I get null for userService. For example:

```
public class EmailAvailableValidator {
    @Inject
    private static UserService userService; // This is not resolved :(

    public static Map<String, List<ValidationError>> validateEmailAndGetErrorsIfAny(String email, String emailField) {
        Map<String, List<ValidationError>> errors = new HashMap<String, List<ValidationError>>();
        if (!userService.isEmailAvailable(email)) {
            List<ValidationError> list = new ArrayList<ValidationError>();
            list.add(new ValidationError("", UsuarioResource.getMessageEmailTaken()));
            errors.put(emailField, list);
        }

        return errors;
    }
}
```

The question is, what is correct way to get an instance of an object that doesn't implement an interface? Is it always necessary to implement an interface?
Isn't it supposed that guice knows how to solved UserDao and Email? Why it is not able to instantiate it except in UserController?
I need this instance with its dependencies resolved, I mean with UserDao and Email into it.

The official guice docs were not very helpful for me.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You need to use a Guice Injector to instantiate EmailAvailableValidator.  Your "Global" class is doing that already.  Using the injector creates an instance and then sets all of its injected fields.
2. You might have to use the static injection to fill a static field.  For example, in your configure() method add:

   ```
   requestStaticInjection(UserService.class);
   ```

   However, I haven't personally used it so YMMV.

Reference:

http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Injections

Comment: Adding requestStaticInjection to Module doesn't help in this case for me. Regarding Guice Injector, I read somewhere it is not a good practice using it for instantiations, instead you should use @Inject. I'm very new to Guice, perhaps I'm wrong. 
Thanks for your help.